# Ciclo repetitivo en inactividad del Usuario

Tags: vb.net

Necesito que cada 5 minutos refresque un `ListView` que esta
cargado con una tabla, me funciona la primera vez pero no funciona 
si sigue existiendo inactividad. He probado varias cosas sin éxito.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Principal

    Private Structure LASTINPUTINFO
        Public cbSize As UInteger
        Public dwTime As UInteger
    End Structure

    <DllImport("User32.dll")>

    Private Shared Function GetLastInputInfo(ByRef plii As LASTINPUTINFO) As Boolean
    End Function

    Public Function GetInactiveTime() As Nullable(Of TimeSpan)

         Dim info As LASTINPUTINFO = New LASTINPUTINFO
         info.cbSize = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(info))
         If (GetLastInputInfo(info)) Then
             Return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount - info.dwTime)
         Else
             Return Nothing
         End If

     End Function

    Private Sub Principal_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Timer2.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

         Dim inactiveTime = GetInactiveTime()
         If (inactiveTime Is Nothing) Then
             Label5.Text = "Desconocido"
         ElseIf (inactiveTime.Value.TotalSeconds > 300) Then
             Label5.Text = String.Format("Inactivo por {0}segundos ",        
             inactiveTime.Value.TotalSeconds.ToString("#"))
             Limpiar_lista(Listview1)
             Mostrar_Lista(Listview1)
         Else
             Label5.Text = "Aplicacion Activa"
         End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: hola.. no ocurre el tick? o el tick ocurre y no refresca nada?? puedes poner un messagebox para cerciorarte si ocurre o no?

Comment: El tick ocurre porque cuando entra entra en inactividad el label5 indica los segundos que van transcurriendo, lo que quiero es que cuando llegue a 5 minutos refresque un listview, esto lo hace bien, pero no consigo inicializar de nuevo el timer...[ara q empiece de nuevo...

Comment: aja.. todo eso no lo explicaste en la pregunta... mira [ask].. de paso dime en que parte estas haciendo eso que no funciona, pq en tu codigo no esta por ninguna parte...

Comment: En el evento tick del timer2 esta el código, si lo puse... mientras no sean 5 minutos, label5 muestra "Aplicacion Activa", cuando llega a 300 segundos, limpia la listview y lo  carga de nuevo a través de una tabla, esto me funciona bien, pero si el usuario sigue en inactividad, quiero q cuando se vuelva a cumplir el ciclo (300segundos) me repita el limpiar y mostrar el listview, asi como esta se queda limpiando y mostrando cada segundo, tengo q inicializar el timer, no consigo la forma de hacerlo...

Comment: cada cuanto se ejecuta el timer?

Comment: El timer se inicializa en el load del formulario...por lo tanto si no lo cierro queda activado...

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que despues de los 300 segundos, ya no estas contando 300 segundos mas porque tu codigo, se queda parado en

```
ElseIf (inactiveTime.Value.TotalSeconds > 300) Then
```

eso se ejecuta siempre despues de los 300 segundos.

Lo que podrias hacer, es agregar a nivel del form una variable vuelta:

```
dim vuelta as int = 1;
```

y lo que tenes que agregar es adentro del if:

```
ElseIf (inactiveTime.Value.TotalSeconds > (300*vuelta )) Then
    Label5.Text = String.Format("Inactivo por {0}segundos ",        
    inactiveTime.Value.TotalSeconds.ToString("#"))
    Limpiar_lista(Listview1)
    Mostrar_Lista(Listview1)
    vuelta = vuelta +1
Else
```

y tambien:

```
 Else
    Label5.Text = "Aplicacion Activa"
    vuelta = 1
 End If
```

esa variable sirve para que se ejecute cada 300 segundos (al multiplicar 300 por la vuelta es cada 5 minutos), y cuando la aplicacion vuelve a estar activa, la reiniciamos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta es la solución a mi problema...Saludos

Comment: Sandra.. si no lo hiciste has el [tour] para saber como funcionamos. Mas alla de las gracias, aqui se premia puntuando preguntas y respuestas y aceptando las que sirvieron. Que bueno que te haya servido. Saludos!